# Firefox 72 not displaying CSS Custom Cursor from SVG file

Tags: css, firefox, svg

> **Note:** This question was originally posted at **Webmasters Stack Exchange** ([Firefox 72 not displaying CSS Custom Cursor from SVG file](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/127766/firefox-72-not-displaying-css-custom-cursor-from-svg-file)), because I was focusing on Firefox Browser
>   Capability. However, it turns out I shouldn't have been asking about
>   browser capability at all, but, rather, CSS constraints. So, in the
>   final analysis, this is a CSS question, not a Firefox question. Hence
>   I have reposted the question here on Stack Overflow, as advised by @Rob.

---

I'm currently experimenting with CSS custom cursors:

```
cursor: url(' [... URL HERE...'), auto;
```

and I'm finding that Firefox 72 is not happy with either `SVG` cursors ***or*** `GIF` cursors (though it is entirely happy with `PNG` cursors).

According to: [**Can I Use CSS property: cursor: url()**](https://caniuse.com/#search=css%20cursor%20url) there shouldn't be a problem.

But clearly there is.

Can anyone shed any light on what the issue is here, please?

Is it that:

- Firefox does not support SVG cursors and caniuse.com is misinformed ?
- Firefox *does* support SVG cursors and I am doing something else wrong?

---

**Added:**

Oh. That's odd. Not working on **Chrome 79** either. No idea what's up then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a CSS constraint that the dimensions of the custom cursor image **must not** exceed `128px x 128px`.

When using an SVG file as the custom cursor image, valid dimensions must be ***hardcoded*** into the SVG file.

**Example:**

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     width="100"
     height="100"
     viewBox="0 0 250 250">
```